# command not running when i run show dbs in mongo terminal in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb

When running the following command:

```
mongos --configdb 10.8.15.175:27019,10.8.14.89:27019,10.8.9.100:27019
```

I get this error:

> FailedToParse: mirrored config server connections are not supported;
>   for config server replica sets be sure to use the replica set
>   connection string

Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: sorry for the starting line , but question is when is run mongos --configdb .....

Comment: You don't explain what you want to achieve, nor ask question. Moreover, `mongos` does not exist. `mongo` does.

Comment: @Aif [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/program/mongos/) is the MongoDB sharding router service to route operations to the corresponding shard - that's why the config servers are needed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are running MongoDB 3.4 binaries here? From version 2.2 MongoDB added support for configuration servers to run as a replica set (whereas they used to be a special set of nodes that synced via another mechanism). In 3.4, it became **required** to use replica sets. In this situation you need to specify the name of the replica set of the config, as per @Josh's post:

```
<config replset name>/<host1:port>,<host2:port>,[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

Connection string for communicating with config servers: `<config replset name>/<host1:port>,<host2:port>,[...]`

Comment: How is that supposed to answer the question?